# Data set on sessionStorge is not available on another page on same tab

Tags: javascript, html, dom, session-storage

**UPDATE : Resolved

Hi guys, thank you for the support. Finally I figured out the problem. It was with the - same-origin problem.**
====================================================================**

I have set some data on `sessionStorage` and I have some buttons to load another page on the same tab.

My problem is I can't see the data I saved on `sessionStorage`.
On the debugging console it shows the `sessionStorage` is empty.

This function sets the data on `sessionStorage`

```
function requestDriverListings() {

    var drivers = {};

    sendUserData ({}, "request driver.php", function (request) { listDrivers(request,drivers); console.log(drivers); displayDrivers(drivers);});

    sessionStorage.setItem("drivers", JSON.stringify(drivers.a));

}
```

This function executes on the page loading - "the other page"

```
function driverProfile () {
    var driverId = sessionStorage.getItem("requestedDriver");
    var driver = sessionStorage.getItem("drivers");
    driver = JSON.parse(driver);
    console.log(driver);
    driver = driver.driverId;
    document.getElementById("driverName").innerHTML = driver.name;
    document.getElementById("driverVehicle").innerHTML = driver.driverVehicle;
    document.getElementById("driverLocation").innerHTML = driver.driverLocation;
    //document.getElementById("driverDetails").innerHTML = driver.driverDetails;


}
```

Please help me to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: as others have suggested, sessionStorage is available within the same tab (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Can you confirm that this is what you're trying to achieve? If so, can you provide a minimal reproductivle example?

Comment: Hi, I just remembered that I was using ````window.location.assign()```` for directing to the other web page. (ON THE SAME TAB). Does it has something to do with?

Comment: Taking a deeper look at your code, it looks like drivers is set to the empty object, and you are trying to save drivers.a to sessionStorage which will be undefined. So you have the additional problem of not setting the driver data correctly before you try to save it to sessionStorage.

Comment: "Does it has something to do with?" I don't think so, as long as you stay in the same tab. First thing you should do is to make sure your code works in the first page (ie. the variable is stored, before loading a different page). And, again,  a minimal reproducible example will help. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @tantalum Yes, Code works on the first page. I can see what I have stored. But I can't see that on the second page. Even I have tried with ````localStorage```` but no results.

Comment: @tantalum Just to mention that ````drivers```` object is empty but it is being applied data on the execution of ````sendUserData()````.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the support. Finally I figured out the problem. It was with the  - ````same-origin```` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Session Storage is limited to specific tab. Data in Session Storage is accessible in the application running tab, so if you are trying to access it in another tab, then you'll get it as undefined or data does not exists.

Instead you can use Local Storage if you have large data, else with smaller data, you can also use cookies.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C Schools:

> The sessionStorage object stores data for only one session (the data is deleted when the browser tab is closed).

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp.

Therefore, the expectation is that the data in `sessionStorage` is only available to the tab that set the data. If you want the data to be available across tabs you will need to look at other options, like `localStorage` although `localStorage` doesn't clear the data once the tab (i.e. session) is closed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I was trying with it on the same tab. Not on a new tab.

Comment: Hi, I just remembered that I was using window.location.assign() for directing to the other web page. (ON THE SAME TAB). Does it has something to do with?

Comment: I tried even with ````localStorage```` but same results. There is no data in ````localStorage```` on the page I want to load.